# Is there a word can I use to express the fact that a piece of music has no notes in?

Tags: terminology

I was wondering if there was a word to describe a (lack of) tonality of a piece of music - or section of a piece of music - to the extent that it is without any identifiable notes? A couple of examples would be *They're Coming to Take Me Away, Ha-Haaa!* and *The Whisper Song* (warning - a bit rude, if you don't know it!).

*4′33″* would also fit the bill, I suppose...

Comment: At least one of the songs you used as and example has notes that are sung.

Comment: Hmm - what bit of which song?

Comment: Well They're coming to take me away has a melody that you can sing. The notes are different.  The Whisper song is closer to being monotone as it's hard to make a musical sound by whispering.

Comment: I don't personally hear *They're coming to take me away* as a melody, just exaggerated spoken intonation - I wonder if we're listening to the same version?

Comment: You said " section of a piece of music - without any identifiable notes" - do you mean lyrics that are only spoken and not sung or would a drum solo also fit that definition?

Comment: A drum solo could be another example - although of course some drums have very definite pitches! The minimal drums in 'whisper' are a pitched sound, but the pitch envelope on each takes the resultant sound away from being 'notes', to my ear/mind.

Comment: I don't know a specific word for what you are looking for but hopefully someone will provide a useful answer.

Comment: Are you just referring to music that is **unpitched**?

Comment: well we talk about unpitched sounds, so just saying *unpitched music* makes sense I guess!

Comment: In general, I wouldn't lump all the songs you've listed together. Yes the music doesn't have the feel of a central pitch (tonic) or any pitches at all in some, but what drives each piece is different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Unpitched.** It means sounds that have indefinite pitch. *Sprechstimmung* like *They're coming to take me away* or [the *Geographical Fugue*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uZfSolxrLWo) qualifies. Pieces using unpitched percussion certainly qualify. *4'33"* is maybe more conceptual, but it probably qualifies if there isn't any music playing in the background... :D

Answer (score 2):

**Noteless** or perhaps **toneless**.

Music by definition does not require notes, only vocal or instrumental sounds.

I believe most of the serious composers I've known would call noteless music **experimental** or **avant garde**.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe "indeterminate pitch"?  The Beatles piece "A Day in the Life" has one or two passages where the orchestra is instructed to glide from one pitch to another individually.  It seems to fit your description.  Since we are talking here about mainstream pop music, "avantgarde" or "atonal" is not really a fitting label, and "unpitched" also does not fit the bill as we are just talking unsynchronized pitched instruments.

Of course, your example of 4'33" trivially meets the label "unpitched".  And so does a number of purely percussive pieces (note that some percussive instruments have determinate pitch as well, like timpani and cowbells, and some are used melodically, like tubular bells, marimba, glockenspiel, xylophone, celesta...).

So generally your description covers a rather large body of music, large enough that it would probably be a bit difficult to subsume all of it under a single label.

Comment: I wasn't looking for a genre label that has to give an idea of what the piece sounds like - simply a term for music made essentially from sounds of indeterminate pitch. It would cover a wide body of music, but then so would a term like 'polyrhythmic' or 'diatonic'.

Answer (score 0):

The term 'indefinite pitch' is used in Australian schools.

Answer (score -4):

The word you're looking for is Atonal

Comment: atonal just means it's not written in any key, which is very different from "without any identifiable notes", which is not a lack of tonality.  I have no idea what the original poster wants.

Comment: Atonal has come to mean music without a tonal 'center' - so while it could be correct to describe the pieces I've mentioned as atonal, it's lumping them in with works such as 12-tone technique works - I was looking for a term that would distinguish them.

Comment: Which is what I was doing- describing the pieces you mentioned. 12-tone technique works are their own separate thing, no matter how people lump them together.